# Is Bootstrap imported twice?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Am I including the whole Bootstrap css by importing `bootstrap.less` in my `Site.less` file? I am overriding a small number of bootstrap classes.

`~/Content/less/Site.less`; by importing the bootstrap file does the output (Site.css) now contain all bootstrap css?

```
@import "less/bootstrap.less";

.btn {
    background-color: red;
}

.btn-lrg {
      font-size: ...;
}
```

In my HTML I am importing like so:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less" rel="stylesheet"/> <!-- Is this redundant now? -->
<link href="/Content/less/Site.less" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**PS:** Is this the industry standard way of overriding bootstrap classes? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, I'd say you are. You could check this yourself just by looking at the resulting files, couldn't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** chances are you have a lot of redundant CSS now being applied and overridden. Easiest way to check for this is to look in the Developer Tools in your browser. Most of them have decent CSS debuggers now and will you show overridden rules and their source file.

In answer to your secondary question, there isn't really an 'industry standard' to how to work with Bootstrap. There are different practices each with different merits suitable for specific circumstances.

You could override the classes post-compilation like so e.g. compiled `bootstrap.css` defines `.btn` and then you later redefine and override the same selector in your own CSS file.

You could also edit the `bootstrap.less`, directly modifying to suit your styles. This is less portable, but you can end up with leaner code.

One more thing: There is a side issue to note related to performance. As per the [Less docs](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage), using the client-side Less compiler is "not recommended for production."

In fact, it may be even harder to debug. Better pre-compile your Less code into CSS with source maps, that way you can find your way back to the relevant `.less` file from your browser's debugger :)